# Closure compiler dependencies with ES6 modules

Tags: es6-modules, google-closure-compiler

Up until today I've had a project with the following structure

```
js/liba.js
js/libb.js
js/libc.js
other/cat.js
other/dog.js
other/puppy.js
```

This had been compiled in one go using `ADVANCED` and chunked into the files.

```
js/lib.js (root)
other/cat.js
other/dog.js
other/puppy.js
```

In the compiler arguments `cat.js` and `dog.js` depend on `lib.js`.
And `puppy.js` depend on `dog.js`

**Introducing ES Modules**

To help with compiler order I started using ES6 modules.
Before this the order was determined by the order of the arguments to closure compiler.

Now `lib.js` includes all code from `dog.js`. The new `dog.js` is empty.

This is a problem because `dog.js` contain code that is running at startup which should only run on pages referencing `dog.js` and `puppy.js` but not on pages referencing `cat.js`.

By using `--output_manifest` I could verify that `dog.js` indeed is listed among `liba.js`, `libb.js` and `libc.js`

When I remove `dog.js` and `puppy.js` from the compiler arguments I get expected result in `lib.js` and `cat.js`. No compilation errors about missing dependencies.

**Export**

The file `dog.js` contain `export` statements that is consumed in `puppy.js`.

My guess is that files with `export` are bundled into the root file (`lib.js`).

How does closure compiler decide to bundle the content of a file into the root node rather than the original file?

Can I use ES6 modules to share code between separate files without having the code bundled in the root after running the closure compiler?